# Copy Product data and Attributes to Another existing product

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-attribute

i know we can use duplicate option. but i don't want to create another new product.

Product 1 -> Product 2

Product 1 and Product 2 are two different products and now i need to copy Product 1 data and its attributes to Product 2 without chaining Product 2 id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by the following

```
<?php

class Copier_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

/**
 * copy the arrtibutes and its value of product  
 * 
 * @param Array $data 
 * 
 * @return void
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 * 
 */ 
public function copy($data) {

        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $currentProduct = $productModel->load($data['productId']);

        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $copyProduct = $productModel->load($productModel->getIdBySku($data['sku']));

        $currentSku = $currentProduct->getSku();

        $restrictedAttributes = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('copier/restricted/attributes'));

        $copyData = $this->_removeRestrictedAttributes($copyProduct->getData(), $restrictedAttributes);

        $currentProduct
                ->setTypeId($copyProduct->getTypeId())
                ->setAttributeSetId($copyProduct->getAttributeSetId())
                ->setStoreId($copyProduct->getStoreId());

        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $productId = $currentProduct->save()->getId();
        $currentProduct = $productModel->load($productId);

        $currentProduct
                ->setData($copyData)
                ->setStoreId($copyProduct->getStoreId())
                ->setSku($currentSku)
                ->setCategoryIds($copyProduct->getCategoryIds())
                ->setWebsiteIDs($copyProduct->getWebsiteIDs());

        //$currentProduct->save();

        /* Prepare Related*/
        $data = array();
        $copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->useRelatedLinks();
        $attributes = array();
        foreach ($copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->getAttributes() as $_attribute) {
            if (isset($_attribute['code'])) {
                $attributes[] = $_attribute['code'];
            }
        }
        foreach ($copyProduct->getRelatedLinkCollection() as $_link) {
            $data[$_link->getLinkedProductId()] = $_link->toArray($attributes);
        }
        $currentProduct->setRelatedLinkData($data);

        /* Prepare UpSell*/
        $data = array();
        $copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->useUpSellLinks();
        $attributes = array();
        foreach ($copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->getAttributes() as $_attribute) {
            if (isset($_attribute['code'])) {
                $attributes[] = $_attribute['code'];
            }
        }
        foreach ($copyProduct->getUpSellLinkCollection() as $_link) {
            $data[$_link->getLinkedProductId()] = $_link->toArray($attributes);
        }
        $currentProduct->setUpSellLinkData($data);

        /* Prepare Cross Sell */
        $data = array();
        $copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->useCrossSellLinks();
        $attributes = array();
        foreach ($copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->getAttributes() as $_attribute) {
            if (isset($_attribute['code'])) {
                $attributes[] = $_attribute['code'];
            }
        }
        foreach ($copyProduct->getCrossSellLinkCollection() as $_link) {
            $data[$_link->getLinkedProductId()] = $_link->toArray($attributes);
        }
        $currentProduct->setCrossSellLinkData($data);

        /* Prepare Grouped */
        $data = array();
        $copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->useGroupedLinks();
        $attributes = array();
        foreach ($copyProduct->getLinkInstance()->getAttributes() as $_attribute) {
            if (isset($_attribute['code'])) {
                $attributes[] = $_attribute['code'];
            }
        }
        foreach ($copyProduct->getGroupedLinkCollection() as $_link) {
            $data[$_link->getLinkedProductId()] = $_link->toArray($attributes);
        }
        $currentProduct->setGroupedLinkData($data);

        $currentProduct->save();

        $fromProduct = $copyProduct->getId();
        $toProduct = $currentProduct->getId();

        $this->_deleteCustomOption($toProduct);

        $this->_changeStock($fromProduct, $toProduct);
        $this->_saveCustomOption($fromProduct, $toProduct);

        $copyProduct->getResource()->duplicate($fromProduct, $toProduct);

}

/**
 * remove rested attributes for the array
 * 
 * @param Array $copyData
 * @param Array $restrictedAttributes
 *  
 * @return Array;
 */
protected function _removeRestrictedAttributes($copyData, $restrictedAttributes){

    foreach ($restrictedAttributes as $_attributes) {
        unset($copyData[$_attributes]);
    }

    return $copyData;   
}

/**
 * copy the stock status 
 * 
 * @param Int $fromProduct - Id of the product used for copying data
 * @param Int $toProduct - Id of the product used to copy data
 * 
 * @return void
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 * 
 */
private function _changeStock($fromProduct, $toProduct) {

    $fromStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($fromProduct);
    $toStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($toProduct);
    if (!$toStockItem->getId()) {
        $toStockItem->setData('product_id', $toProduct);
        $toStockItem->setData('stock_id', $fromStockItem->getData('stock_id'));
    }

    $toStockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $fromStockItem->getData('is_in_stock'));
    $toStockItem->setData('manage_stock', $fromStockItem->getData('manage_stock'));

    try {
        $toStockItem->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * delete the custom option of the gien product  
 * 
 * @param Int $deleteId - Id of the product used to delete the option 
 * 
 * @return void
 * 
 */ 
private function _deleteCustomOption($deleteId) {
    $catalogModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $opt = $catalogModel->load($deleteId);

    foreach ($opt->getOptions() as $o) {
        $o->delete();
    }

    $opt->setHasOptions(0)->save();

}

/**
 * copy the custome option
 * 
 * @param Int $fromProduct - Id of the product used for copying option
 * @param Int $toProduct - Id of the product used to copy option
 * 
 * @return void
 * 
 */
private function _saveCustomOption($fromProduct, $toProduct) {

    $copyProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($fromProduct);
    $currentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($toProduct);

    if($copyProduct->getHasOptions()){
        $copyProduct->getOptionInstance()->duplicate($fromProduct, $toProduct);
        $currentProduct->setHasOptions(1)->save();
    }
 }
}
```

i added a new tab in the admin product grid with the id "copier" and the add a input with name "copier"

used this function in the a button onclick

```
   (function(){new Copyer(document.getElementById('copier'),[productId]);})();
```

```
    (function(w){
        var log = function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        };
        Event.observe(w, 'load', function(){
            $('product_edit_form').insert({
              top: $('product_info_tabs_copier_content').writeAttribute('id','copier_content').show()
            }); 
            $('product_info_tabs_copier').up().remove();
        });

        var Copyer = Class.create();
        Copyer.prototype = {
            initialize: function(data,productId) {
                this.field = $(data);
                this.productId = productId;
                this.copy();
            },
            copy: function() {
                this.field.addClassName('required-entry');
                if(Validation.validate(this.field)){
                    var r = confirm("Are you sure to copy data from "+this.field.getValue() 
                        + ".\nThis process is irreversible."
                    );
                    if (r == true) {
                        this.updateAttribute(this.field.getValue(),this.productId);
                    }

                }
                this.field.removeClassName('required-entry');
            },
            updateAttribute: function(sku,productId) {

                 var url = 'helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("copier/process/index"); ?>';
                 var data = {
                    'sku':sku,
                    'productId':productId
                 };
                 new Ajax.Request(url, {
                    method: 'post',
                    parameters: {
                        data: Object.toJSON(data)
                    },
                    onFailure: function() {
                        alert('An error occurred while saving the data.');
                    },
                    onSuccess: function(response) {
                        data = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                        if (data.error) {
                            alert("Error : " + data.message);
                        } else {
                            w.location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        w.Copyer = Copyer;
    })(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

sunel,It too complex to do this type of works.I am suggesting to export fields of product A from D`ataflow export or Import/export section` of `Admin>System`.Then u`sing import that data to product B and note that on the export sheet put product B sku instead of A's Sku`.

Comment: Hi Amit i managed to achieve it u can check my answer may its correct